# How to make a view as high as its content

Tags: swift, layout, swiftui

How can I make a view having a minimum size, a maximum size and inbetween consuming as much vertical space as it's content requires?

```
struct SubView<Content: View>: View {
    
    private let content: () -> Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            Text("Text")
                .padding([.leading, .trailing])
            
            ZStack {
                Color(.red)
                self.content()
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct SubView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            SubView {
                Text("A")
            }
            SubView {
                VStack {
                    Text("A")
                    Text("B")
                    Text("C")
                    Text("D")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

In the example above, both views are sized to maximum size. But I want to have both rectangles take the size of their content, like so:

[image]

So far I only figured out how to set the fixed height or a infinite maxHeight using the frame modifier but non of these brings the required result.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is the problem the red view not big enough, or the content inside is not big enough?

Comment: I added a "how it should look like" picture to make things more clear. I want to size the red rectangle depending of it's content height. So it should be as small as possible and grow with the content (if possible until a defineable maxHeight is reached)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move `Color.red` to the background (instead of `ZStack`):

```
struct SubView<Content: View>: View {
    // ...

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Text")
                .padding([.leading, .trailing])
            
            self.content()
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .fill(Color.red)
                )
                .padding([.leading, .trailing])
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a cool idea. I guess if I'd like to have an aditionall max-height feature I then add a nother layer around the self.content() and give that layer the maximumHeight

Comment: @lenny Yes, in the solution above the height of the red rectangle is based on the height of the `content()` (and its padding... - basically on everything which is above the background modifier). You can, if you want, set the frame height/maxHeight explicitly (eg. in the same place where the `maxWidth` is set).